# MacOS Intermittently drops 5Ghz Wifi Connection

Tags: macos, wifi, audio, bluetooth, airport

I know there is a plethora of questions pertaining to MacOS and Wifi Connections dropping, but hear me out.

I'm running:

- Machine: `Macbook 16" i7 Big Sur 11.2`
- AP: `Unifi AC Mesh (Running both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz (SSID: Rootman-Home)`
- Router: `Unifi Security Gateway`
- Bluetooth Headset: `Sony WH-1000XM3`

Ever since I got my Macbook my 5Ghz home Wifi has been dropping at really odd times, sometimes once every other hour, sometimes once every other day. When it drops I'm unable to reconnect to the same SSID for 5Ghz for at least about 2 - 4 minutes, I'm able to instantly join the 2.4Ghz channels no problem.

One time, I noticed as I pulled my wireless headset from it's charging cable (it was charing from the Macbook via a dongle) my wifi just dropped. Today, my headset was connected via Bluetooth and when the Wifi dropped again, I tried reconnecting and same issue, I switched my Bluetooth headset off and it reconnected instantly.

Went through the logs and found this (this happened at the time of the Wifi disconnecting):

```
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.638 Info: <airport[213]> TRIMMED QUERY SCAN CACHE request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.643 Info: <airport[213]> QUERY GAS CACHE request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.643 Info: <airport[213]> QUERY ALL WIFI NETWORKS request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.645 Info: <airport[213]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.645 Info: <airport[213]> QUERY ALL WIFI NETWORKS request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:42:51.645 Info: <airport[213]> QUERY ALL WIFI NETWORKS request received from pid 501 (WiFiAgent)
Mon Feb  8 13:43:04.727 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:43:04.727 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 6
Mon Feb  8 13:43:34.731 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:43:34.732 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 5
Mon Feb  8 13:44:04.732 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:44:04.732 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 5
Mon Feb  8 13:44:34.734 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:44:34.734 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 4
Mon Feb  8 13:45:04.731 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:45:04.731 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 5
Mon Feb  8 13:45:34.734 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:45:34.734 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 5
Mon Feb  8 13:46:04.731 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioMonitoringCallback: Bluetooth Audio Notification
Mon Feb  8 13:46:04.731 BTC: <airport[213]> BluetoothCoexAudioNotificationProcess: BT Audio: AUDIO_RETRANSMISSION = 5
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.421 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: LINK_CHANGED (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.422 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.976 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.976 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.976 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.976 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.977 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:15.977 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.021 AutoJoin: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __updateAutoJoinRetryIntervals]: On AC power, changing to active retry interval.
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 AutoJoin: <airport[213]> _handleLinkEvent: Unexpected link down. Triggering auto-join.
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 AutoJoin: <airport[213]> BEST CONNECTED SCAN CANCELLED on interface en0
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem __submitLinkChangeMetric:involuntary:interface:network:linkDownReason:linkDownSubreason:isAWDLUp:awdlState:lastSecurityIssueCount:]: link change metric data: CWAWDMetricLinkChangeData: isLinkUp: NO, isInVol: YES, reason: 2, subreason: 1, channel: 0 (0MHz/0), oui: aa:aa:aa, flags: 0x0, securityType: 0x0, awdlState: 4, rssiHistory: [0, 0, 0], htInfo: 0x0, vhtInfo: 0x0
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWAWDManager submitMetric:]: submitting metric id 0x90009
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __manageProblematicNetworks:addProblematic:reason:]: Adding Rootman-Home to list of potentially problematic networks.
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 AutoJoin: <airport[213]> AUTO-JOIN trigger requested (Link Down)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: SSID_CHANGED (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Info: <WiFiAge[501]> current=(no_assoc) changed=(no_assoc, 3bars)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.028 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 BTC: <airport[213]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: <en0> Handle Bluetooth Coex: FrequencyBand <2>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization <56>, Clamshell Mode <1>
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 BTC: <airport[213]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: Driver supports APPLE80211_CAP_COEX_PROFILE_OFFLOAD. Airportd won't BluetoothCoexModeSet() and defer coex profile loading to UDM coex manager (UCM/WRM) ...
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: BSSID_CHANGED (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 Info: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: BSSID changed, not running HOSTAP, and not associated
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 BTC: <airport[213]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: <en0> Handle Bluetooth Coex: FrequencyBand <2>, Bluetooth Bandwidth Utilization <56>, Clamshell Mode <1>
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 BTC: <airport[213]> __BluetoothCoexHandleUpdateForNode: Driver supports APPLE80211_CAP_COEX_PROFILE_OFFLOAD. Airportd won't BluetoothCoexModeSet() and defer coex profile loading to UDM coex manager (UCM/WRM) ...
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DUMP_LOGS (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.029 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: LINK_CHANGED (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.030 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: DRIVER_AVAILABLE (en0)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.030 Info: <airport[213]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.030 Driver Event: <airport[213]> _bsd_80211_event_callback: driver available (reason=0xe0823805, subreason=0xe3ff8808, flags=0x2)
Mon Feb  8 13:46:16.030 Info: <airport[213]> systemWokenByWiFi: System wake reason: <EC.Bluetooth>, was not woken by WiFi
```

I'm new to MacOS, but what it looks like to me is somehow it's trying to query information from the headset, it's not working, this then causes some kind of event where MacOS decides to review/reconnect to currently connected devices, this leads it to kick off the 5Ghz SSID (maybe some kind of bug) and temporarily black list it. After it sorts out the Bluetooth connection to my headset, it then re-allows a review of blacklisted devices and lets me back in to my 5Ghz.

Some solutions suggested I disable Wake on Lan (Or Wake on Wifi), I've done this, and I'm gonna give it a few days and see if this fixes the issue.

Other solutions I've tried:

1. Restarting my Macbook.
2. Reconfiguring and resetting my network.
3. Disabling Bluetooth and re-pairing BT devices.
4. Formatting / Re-installing MacOS (I did this a few months ago).

I really don't wanna take this machine in to be repaired, I don't want to sit without a work station for a couple of days so I'd rather sort the issue out myself.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me make sense of these logs.

=== UPDATE (16/02/2021)
The wifi disconnected again with the same error as before.
I've cleared bluetooth devices and re-paired them, the issue is definitely related to my bluetooth headset.

I've now increased the channel width of my 5Ghz radio from HT40 to HT80. So far it's been a day without any failures. We'll see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: While I have no personal experience with this issue I have seen some Bluetooth devices interfere with WiFi. You could narrow it down to that by just turning off the headsets for [insert reasonable amount of time here] and see if the problem recurs...

Comment: @SteveChambers Could be days without a DC. It's really difficult to replicate, but the logs are there and are consistent when the Wifi does dc. I'm really confident the answer lies in the logs, just need someone who knows MacOS and it's internal processes, like Airport, well enough to tell me if there's something wrong with my mac or if this is just a BT Device causing trouble. But in the meanwhile, I am trying different combinations and other solutions.